# How can I make the page link appear along side the title?

Tags: php, sql, search

I'm working on a search function of a flat HTML site and I've got it working but I want to add the page link to the results so people can navigate there but the page_link column won't appear next to it how can I make it appear?

if(isset($_GET['keywords'])) {

```
$keywords = $dbc->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);

$query = $dbc->query("
    SELECT page_title
    FROM contents
    WHERE page_contents LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
    OR page_title LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
");

}
?>

<div class="result-count"> 
Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> result(s).
</div>

<?php 
if($query->num_rows) {
while($r = $query->fetch_object()) {
?>
<div class="result"> 
<?php 
echo $r->page_title, $r->page_link; 
?>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please provide clear and specific information on how your database looks like. What exactly isn't working? Do you get an error?

Comment: Please take some time to read how you can ask your question in a better way. Also before you ask something be sure that you already did your investigation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <?php 
    echo '<a href=' . $r->page_link . '>' . $r->page_title . '</a>; 
  ?>
```